# Mongoose query inside a loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to develop a simple application with mongoose.
Given an array of username 'group.contacts', I want to get the corresponding IDs of these user. However, the loop does not work as expected: the loop continues before the .find() method finish so I cannot get all the IDs of people. How can I solve this problem?

```
for(var v = 0; v < group.contacts.length; v++) {
    PersonModel.find({
        name: group.contacts[v]
    }, function (err, person) {
        if(!err && person) {
            console.log('Found ' + person._id + ' ' + v); 
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the $in operator. Makes it much easier.

Comment: thanks, I used it and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PersoModel
.where('name').in(group.contacts)
.exec(function(person){
   console.log('Found ' + person._id + ' ' + person.name); 
});
```